# Declare passed parameter to var in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to create a function that takes 2 parameters and changes their values. Example:

```
var geometricSprite = SKSpriteNode()
var geoTouched = true
removeTouch(sprite: geometricSprite, bool: getTouched)

func removeTouch(sprite: SKSpriteNode, bool: Bool) {
    sprite.size = 0

    bool = false
    //HERE I GET THE ERROR "Cannot assign to value: 'bool' is a 'let' constant"
}
```

So again `bool = false` gives an error because 'bool' is a let constant. I never declared that bool as a let so I do not know how to fix this error.

Comment: Are you just trying to assign to it or are you also looking to change the value of `getTouched` that was passed to it?

Comment: I am trying to change the value to "false". But the error appears!

Comment: You don't need to have declared it.  In the Swift manual, "Functions": "Function parameters are constants by default."

Answer (score 3):

Since your are looking to both pass and argument to the function *and* modify the value that was passed in you need to define that parameter as `inout`:

```
func removeTouch(sprite: SKSpriteNode, bool: inout Bool)
```

That also changes the call site to require a `&` before the value being passed in

```
removeTouch(sprite: geometricSprite, bool: &getTouched)
```

---

That said, depending on what you are doing with the value that was passed to the function, you are probably better off returning the new value.

```
func removeTouch(sprite: SKSpriteNode, bool: Bool) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify a function parameter as `inout`, you may not *mutate* it.

`SKSpriteNode()` is of type `class`, which is a reference type: not marking it `inout` means you *may not mutate the reference itself*, whereas you may, however, mutate mutable (accessible) members of the reference type (accessible via the non-mutable reference).

`bool`, on the other hand, is a value type, which means that you may not mutate it when supplying it as an argument, unless you explicitly mark it as `inout`.

A hopefully instructive example:

```
class MyReferenceType {
    var valueTypeMember: Int = 0
}

struct MyValueType {
    var valueTypeMember: Int = 0
}

func mutateMyReferenceAndValueInstances(
    _ ref: MyReferenceType, _ val: inout MyValueType) {
    ref.valueTypeMember = 42
    val.valueTypeMember = 43
}

let ref = MyReferenceType()
var val = MyValueType()

print(ref.valueTypeMember, val.valueTypeMember) // 0 0
mutateMyReferenceAndValueInstances(ref, &val)
print(ref.valueTypeMember, val.valueTypeMember) // 42 43
```

See e.g. [the Language Guide - Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) for details regarding in-out parameters.